# How to call a class from another class c#

Tags: c#

I am calculating BMI using 4 methods. How do I call a method from the main. The code compiles but does not gives the desired output. Should I add methods instead of classes? The output just asks me to enter something and terminates. Any help would help

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {       
        LbToKg Kgs = new LbToKg();
        InchesToMeters Mts = new InchesToMeters();
        BMIMetric BMiMet = new BMIMetric();
        BMICategory BMICat = new BMICategory();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    class LbToKg
    {
        public double LbsToKg(double lbs)
        {
            lbs = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            double kilograms = lbs * 0.45359237;
            Console.WriteLine(lbs + " pounds is " + kilograms + " kilograms");
            Console.ReadLine();
            return kilograms;
        }
    }
    class InchesToMeters
    {
        public double InchToMeters(double inches)
        {
            inches = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            double meters = inches / 39.37;
            Console.WriteLine(inches + " inches is " + meters + " meters");
            return meters;

        }
    }
    class BMIMetric
    {
        public double BMIMetrics(double kilograms, double meters)
        {
            double bmi = kilograms / (meters * meters);
            Console.WriteLine("Your BMI is:{0}", Math.Round(bmi, 4));
            return bmi;
        }
    }
    class BMICategory
    {
        public static void BMICategories(double bmi)
        {
            if (bmi < 18.5)
                Console.WriteLine("You are underweight.");
            else if (bmi > 18.5 && bmi < 24.9)
                Console.WriteLine("You're normal weight.");
            else if (bmi > 25.0 && bmi < 29.9)
                Console.WriteLine("You're Overweight.");
            else if (bmi > 30.0)
                Console.WriteLine("You are Obese"); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you should be doing it with static methods, since you dont need a class.

Comment: Your code doesn't do anything but create some instances of your classes. You're not calling the instance methods e.g. `var kg = Kgs.LbsToKg(24);`

Comment: This looks like a good time to start with some introductory tutorials on C#.  You seem to be confusing yourself in this code.

Comment: Also: Do get the terminology right: A class is like a recipe, not like a cake. You can only call static class methods. Other functions can only be called on instances (cakes) of a class..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are little bit off the track: you define classes with methods and you are using just constructors of those classes, which isn't doing anything, instead you want to call methods that you defined. So they shouldnt be wrapped in any class, just methods on `Program` class. More over, they should be static, as you want to call them in `static Main` method. So, your code should be:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {       
        double kgs = LbsToKg();
        double mts = InchToMeters();
        double bmiMet = BMIMetrics(kgs, mts);
        BMICategories(bmiMet);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    // you don't need paramteter - you collect it from the user
    public static  double LbsToKg()
    {
        double lbs = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        double kilograms = lbs * 0.45359237;
        Console.WriteLine(lbs + " pounds is " + kilograms + " kilograms");
        Console.ReadLine();
        return kilograms;
    }
    // you don't need paramteter - you collect it from the user
    public static double InchToMeters()
    {
        double inches = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        double meters = inches / 39.37;
        Console.WriteLine(inches + " inches is " + meters + " meters");
        return meters;

    }

    public static double BMIMetrics(double kilograms, double meters)
    {
        double bmi = kilograms / (meters * meters);
        Console.WriteLine("Your BMI is:{0}", Math.Round(bmi, 4));
        return bmi;
    }

    public static void BMICategories(double bmi)
    {
        if (bmi < 18.5)
            Console.WriteLine("You are underweight.");
        else if (bmi > 18.5 && bmi < 24.9)
            Console.WriteLine("You're normal weight.");
        else if (bmi > 25.0 && bmi < 29.9)
            Console.WriteLine("You're Overweight.");
        else if (bmi > 30.0)
            Console.WriteLine("You are Obese"); 
    }

}
```

Comment: Since the BMICategories is a void method. I get an error in the main saying  Error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'double' (CS0029)

Comment: Ranges are not consistent; what if `bmi == 29.95`?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Well, that is other problem, but it's rather debugging one.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest implementing business logics in a *single* class:

```
public class Bmi {
  public Bmi(double inches, double lbs) {
    if (inches <= 0.0)
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(inches));
    else if (lbs <= 0.0)
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(lbs));

    Inches = inches;
    Lbs = lbs;
  }

  public double Lbs    {get;}
  public double Kg     => Lbs * 0.45359237;
  public double Inches {get;}
  public double Meters => Inches / 39.37;
  public double Index  => Kg / (Meters * Meters);

  public string Description {
    get {
      double bmi = Index;

      if (bmi < 18.5) 
        return "underweight";
      else if (bmi < 24.9) 
        return "normal weight"; 
      else if (bmi < 29.9) 
        return "overweight";
      else 
        return "obese";
    }
  }

  public override string ToString() => Description;
}
```

Let's extract `ReadDouble` as well:

```
public static double ReadDouble(string title) {
  Console.WriteLine(title);

  while (true) {
    if (double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out double result))
      return result;

    Console.WriteLine("Sorry, invalid syntax. Please, provide floating point value.");
  }
}
```

Then you can use it:

```
   static void Main(string[] args) {
     Bmi bmi = new Bmi(
       ReadDouble("Please, enter your height in inches:"),
       ReadDouble("Please, enter your weight in lbs:")
     );

     Console.WriteLine($"You are {bmi.Description}");

     Console.ReadKey();
   }
```

Note, that, you can easily provide more info, say

```
   Console.WriteLine($"You are {bmi.Description} with BMI index {bmi.Index:f2}");
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't call any methods, try something like this:

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args) {
    var bmi = BMIMetric.BMIMetrics(70, 170);
    BMICategory.BMICategories(bmi);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work for you.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double kilograms = ConsoleConvertors.LbsToKg();
    double Mts = ConsoleConvertors.InchToMeters();
    double BMiMet = ConsoleConvertors.BMIMetrics();
    double BMICat = ConsoleConvertors.BMICategories();
}

public static class  ConsoleConvertors
{
    public static double LbsToKg()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("LbsToKg - Enter lsb:");
        var lbs = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        double kilograms = lbs * 0.45359237;
        Console.WriteLine(lbs + " pounds is " + kilograms + " kilograms");
        return kilograms;
    }
    public static double InchToMeters()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("InchToMeters - Enter inch:");
        var inches = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        double meters = inches / 39.37;
        Console.WriteLine(inches + " inches is " + meters + " meters");
        return meters;
    }
    public static double BMIMetrics( )
    {
        Console.WriteLine("BMIMetrics - Enter kilograms :");
        var kilograms = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("BMIMetrics - Enter meters :");
        var metter = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        double bmi = kilograms / (metter * metter);
        Console.WriteLine("Your BMI is:{0}", Math.Round(bmi, 4));
        return bmi;
    }
    public static double BMICategories()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("BMICategories - Enter bmi :");
        var bmi = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        if (bmi < 18.5)
            Console.WriteLine("You are underweight.");
        else if (bmi > 18.5 && bmi < 24.9)
            Console.WriteLine("You're normal weight.");
        else if (bmi > 25.0 && bmi < 29.9)
            Console.WriteLine("You're Overweight.");
        else if (bmi > 30.0)
            Console.WriteLine("You are Obese");

        return bmi;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here is that you are creating objects `Kgs`, `Mts`, etc. but never calling the methods `LbsToKg`, `InchToMeters`, etc.  To call them, you would use `Kgs.LbsToKgs();` and `Mts.InchToMeters();`.

Normally you would use methods without separate classes for this kind of program. Here is one way to write your program with minimal changes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace bmiCalculator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double kg = LbsToKg();
            double m = InchToMeters();
            double bmi = BMIMetrics(kg, m);

            BMICategories(bmi); 

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static double LbsToKg()
        {
            Console.Write("Weight in lbs: ");
            double lbs = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            double kilograms = lbs * 0.45359237;
            Console.WriteLine(lbs + " pounds is " + kilograms + " kilograms");
            return kilograms;
        }

        public static double InchToMeters()
        {
            Console.Write("Height in inches: ");
            double inches = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            double meters = inches / 39.37;
            Console.WriteLine(inches + " inches is " + meters + " meters");
            return meters;
        }

        public static double BMIMetrics(double kilograms, double meters)
        {
            double bmi = kilograms / (meters * meters);
            Console.WriteLine("Your BMI is:{0}", Math.Round(bmi, 4));
            return bmi;
        }

        public static void BMICategories(double bmi)
        {
            if (bmi < 18.5)
                Console.WriteLine("You are underweight.");
            else if (bmi > 18.5 && bmi < 24.9)
                Console.WriteLine("You're normal weight.");
            else if (bmi > 25.0 && bmi < 29.9)
                Console.WriteLine("You're Overweight.");
            else if (bmi > 30.0)
                Console.WriteLine("You are Obese"); 
        }
    }
}
```